# Variable not being set to msg.sender in constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment

Having a weird issue with Solidity and web3.js 1.0. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract Test {

    address public contractOwner;

    function TestContract() public {
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    function foo() constant returns(address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

}
```

However calling the automatically-generated getter method for the `address public contractOwner` produces an unexpected result.

```
> var deployed;
undefined
> var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
undefined
> accounts[0]
'0x78924d231848a2d37781e42A2Fe30737F19b6c5E'
> contract.deploy({data: bytecode}).send({
... from: accounts[0],
... gas: 3000000
... }).then((_deployed) => { deployed = _deployed })
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> deployed.setProvider(provider)
true
> deployed.methods.foo().call().then(console.log)
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> 0x78924d231848a2d37781e02A2Fe30v37F19b6c5E
> deployed.methods.contractOwner().call().then(console.log)
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

As you can see, `foo()` works perfectly, but `contractOwner()` returns an empty address. Should it not be `0x78924d231848a2d37781e42A2Fe30737F19b6c5E`, which is what's passed as the `from` attribute during deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the mismatch between the contract name, `Test`, and the name of what was probably meant to be your constructor, `TestContract`.

Because `TestContract` was never executed, `owner` was never assigned a value, so it retains its zero value (`address(0)`). Rename either the contract or the function so it works as a constructor.

Comment: Deleted my answer because your's correct.